# Symfony2 Service with an unique instance

Tags: symfony, service, scope, singleton

Please i need some help:

I have the following services:

SERVICE CONFIGURATION IN services.yml

services:

```
xpad.producto_repository:
     class: Xpad\ProductoBundle\Entity\ProductRepository
     factory_service: doctrine.orm.clientes_entity_manager
     factory_method: getRepository
     arguments:
         - Xpad\ProductoBundle\Entity\Product


backend_cliente.producto_filters:
     class: Xpad\BackendClienteBundle\Filters\ProductFilters
     calls:
         - [setRepository, ["@xpad.producto_repository="]]
     scope: container
```

AND THE CLASS FOR backend_cliente.producto_filters IS:

```
namespace Xpad\BackendClienteBundle\Filters;

use Xpad\ProductoBundle\Entity\ProductRepository;

class ProductFilters
{
    private $_queryBuilder;


    public function getQueryBuilder()
    {
        return $this->_queryBuilder;
    }

    public function setQueryBuilder($queryBuilder)
    {
        $this->_queryBuilder = $queryBuilder;
    }

    public function setRepository(ProductRepository $productRepository = null)
    {
        if($this->_queryBuilder == null)
        {
            $this->_queryBuilder = $productRepository->createQueryBuilder('p');
        }
    }
}
```

AND I HAVE THE FOLLOWING ACTION IN ONE OF MY CONTROLLERS:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{ 
 ............
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
      //SOME CODE

       $service_filter = $this->container->get('backend_cliente.producto_filters');
       $queryBuilder = $service_filter->getQueryBuilder();

      //SOME OTHER CODE
    }
```

MY PROBLEM IS: ANYTIME THAT THE indexAction is execute I GOT A NEW INSTANCE OF backend_cliente.producto_filters SERVICE AND I DON'T KNOW WHY. I NEED AND UNIQUE INSTANCE AS A SINGLETON BECAUSE A HAVE THE $_queryBuilder ATRIBUTTE AND I NEED TO GET THE VALUE OF IT JUST MODIFY ITS VALUE WHEN IS NEEDED;

PLEASE HELP I DON KNOW WHAT I'M DOING WRONG.

Comment: Are you expecting your instance to survive across multiple web requests because that is not going to happen.  Or are you making a bunch of sub requests to indexAction?  By the way, you have an = in your service name "@xpad.producto_repository=".  So your posted code will not work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have to use the class as a service?

Why don't you use a Singleton, without using a service? Like this:

```
namespace Xpad\BackendClienteBundle\Filters;

use Xpad\ProductoBundle\Entity\ProductRepository;

class ProductFilters { 
    private $_queryBuilder;
    private static $reference = null;

    public function getInstance(){
        if (self::$reference === null)
            self::$reference = new ProductFilters();
        return self::$reference;
    }

    private function __construct(){}

    public function getQueryBuilder()
    {
        return $this->_queryBuilder;
    }

    public function setQueryBuilder($queryBuilder)
    {
        $this->_queryBuilder = $queryBuilder;
    }

    public function setRepository(ProductRepository $productRepository = null)
    {
        if($this->_queryBuilder == null)
        {
            $this->_queryBuilder = $productRepository->createQueryBuilder('p');
        }

    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
...
$filter = ProductFilters::getInstance();
...
```

Comment: Sorry for the down vote but Symfony 2 is really built around dependency injection and services.  Most services are singletons.  There really is no reason for explicitly making singleton's in Symfony 2.  Furthermore, it really does not answer the question.  I'm pretty sure @gestherhf actually want his instance to survive across multiple web requests.  And that of course is not going to happen.

Comment: Where do you read that "Symfony 2 is really built around dependency injection and services"?? The fact that the framework supports that funcionalities, doesn't means that is a "dependency injection - based framework" like Spring...

I don´t know if you really works with PHP, but you can't anyway do that an instance survive across multiple web requests!! You can emulate that only, this is not Java or C#, the scripts always has a start and an end when you call them!

He only wanted a Singleton, perhaps he didn't know that he can go outside of a service to do it...

Comment: He asked for a singleton but if you parse his question then I think it's clear that he wants something that survives between request.  Which, as we both know, is challenging with php.  Your singleton example, by the way, ignores the need for a repository.  It's a good example of why dependency injection containers should be used if available.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone could argue against the notion that the Symfony 2 framework is built around dependency injection and services.  Out of the box, the basic framework defines over 350+ services.  If you look at the code, practically every class has it's dependencies injected.