# Symfony - access to variable inside service

Tags: symfony, service

I am looking to access to a variable inside a service.
The variable is an object class.

This is the services.yml

```
services: 
    project.notification:
        class: NotificationsBundle\Command\ServerCommand
```

// this is the class

```
class ServerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    public $notification;
    /**
     * Configure a new Command Line
     */
    protected function configure() { 
        $this->setName('Project:notification:server') ->setDescription('Start the notification server.');

    }

    public function getNotification()
    {  
        return $this->notification;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {

        $this->notification = new Notification();
        $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                $this->notification
            )
        ), 8081);

        $server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function ()  {  
            $this->notification->sendToAll('Hello'); 
        }); 

        $server->run();

    }

}
```

I would like to get the variable $notification from another controller.
When I do that I got an error "non-existent object" ($notification).

I run the service by executing the following command:

```
php app/console Project:notification:server
```

It has to be the current object I can not create a new one because the list of users it is inside the object $notification.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I would like to get the variable $notification from another controller." And this means?

Comment: When I tried to access to the variable $notification I got an non-object error but this variable is set before. It should not get this error.

Comment: From another controller i did
$this->container->get('project.notification')->getNotification()->sendToAll('HEREEE ');
and I got the error aforementioned

Comment: Maybe the error come from this line $this->notification = new Notification(); Symfony doesn't know Notification() class ? did you defined it ?

Comment: Yes, Its is defined and It works well.
I found a similar topic  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867790/symfony2-service-with-an-unique-instance
but the answer did not work because it has to be a service

Comment: You are mixing up services and commands.  ServerCommand::getNotification() is going to return null since it is not initialized.  All I can suggest is reading up a bit on Symfony services until the distinction between services, commands and controllers become clear.

Comment: First, I run the server by executing "php app/console Project:notification:server" its create a new instance of notification inside ServerCommand.
Then, I execute a controller : $this->container->get('project.notification')->sendNotification(' HEREEE ');
It supposed to take the server instance that it was create before and its notification instance in order to execute sendNotification. But this server instance it is not the same because I get a non-object error in notification variable.

Comment: @Minniek The php scripts are stateless, meaning that all data that is not persisted is lost upon completion of the script. So when you create the object in ServerCommand it is only created for the duration of that script and is discarded when the script finishes. The controller starts with a clean slate and therefore cannot find your object.

Comment: But I can access to the notification variable from a js page:
notif = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");
I would like to do the same thing from a new controller

Comment: If I can do that from a js script I should be able to contact to the same service from a new controller